# learning javascript and haven't learned about toString

Tags: numbers, tostring

What is 0xff.toString()? Why?
Now I when I type this on my console I get the output of 255 but why when 0xff is 225 in base 10.

Comment: You're simply wrong. FF in base 16 is 255 decimal.

Answer (score 1):

Because 0xff is not base 10. 0x part of that specifically means this is hexadecimal and 0xff would be 255.

Comment: I see, I'm not sure where I got the 225 from since this is very new to me. Would you say  0xff.toString() is 255 regardless of toString method?

Comment: @1vrxtc9 Hexadecimal 0xff is 255 no matter what you do with it.